# Integrability of the characteristic distribution of almost Dirac structures

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, poisson-geometry

Let $L$ be an almost Dirac structure having an integrable characteristic distribution. What can we say about the involutivity of $L$ under the Courant Bracket? or under which extra conditions can we conclude that $L$ is Dirac?
In particular, if $L$ is the graph of some bivector, is $L$ Dirac?

An almost Dirac structure is a lagrangian (maximally isotropic) subbundle $L \subset \mathbb{T}M := TM \oplus T^*M$ over $M$, with respect to the nondegenerate, symmetric fibrewise bilinear form $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ on $\mathbb{T}M$ given by
$\langle (X,\alpha),(Y,\beta) \rangle = \alpha(Y)+\beta(X).$
The structure $L$ is a Dirac structure if it is involutive with respect to the Courant Bracket
$[\![ \cdot, \cdot ]\!] : \Gamma(\mathbb{T}M) \times \Gamma(\mathbb{T}M) \to \Gamma(\mathbb{T}M)$,
$$ [\![ (X,\alpha), (Y,\beta) ]\!] = ([X,Y], \mathcal{L}_X \beta - \mathbb{i}_Y d\alpha).$$
The anchor map of $L$ is the projection $pr_T : L \to TM$ and its image is called *characteristic distribution*. A Dirac structure has an integrable characteristic distribution.